# Query String being changed

Tags: security, http, query-string

Our customers post links to our site on various social media sites. The query string looks like this:

```
?jid=6559&hjid=754BCDF775239471EB69054403DD9AB6
```

However a small number of requests have an invalid query string when posted back to us. Here are some examples:

```
?jid=655975&hjid=75477OPQS77523947131RO6905440336QQ9NO6
?jid=655945&hjid=75441OPQS77523947125RO6905440344QQ9NO6
```

You can see that all the numbers are left untouched and the letters in the query string values are changed. The invalid values also seem to all follow the same pattern where A-Z values are changed and numbers are left intact.

All of these requests come from the same IP address ranges:

- 209.133.77.163-168
- 89.145.102.202-207

It looks to be some sort of URL fuzzing service. Has anyone seen behavior like this before? If not any ideas on the pattern of the changes?

Comment: Maybe just typo? You will always experience the case where non-existing URLs are requested, regardless if intentionally or unintentionally.

Comment: That is what I thought the first couple times but we get a couple dozen of these per day from different clients and they all have the exact same pattern.

Comment: Well, maybe someone is doing some fuzzing. But if your application can handle these values properly, it shouldn’t be a problem.

Comment: Ya good point. We handle it but log a warning which has been bothering me. Just trying to see if I am missing something before I ignore the log entries.

Comment: Do you have more detailed info about the request such as the user agent of the requester?

Comment: Here is a sample user agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8)